# How is "token auth" any different than "cookie auth"?

Tags: api, authentication, cookies, token

On the surface, it seems like "token auth" is basically the same thing as traditional "cookie auth".

Token auth:

1. User submits username/password to API
2. API responds with access token
3. Client stores access token for identifying user in future requests

Cookie auth:

1. User submits username/password to API
2. API responds with cookie
3. Client stores cookie for identifying user in future requests

It seems that token auth is basically the same as cookie auth, except that most HTTP clients already know how to deal with managing cookies automatically, whereas you have to manually manage API tokens.

What am I missing? What are the benefits of using token auth? Is it really worth the extra effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the extra effort is worth it, depends on what you are protecting and who is consuming the API.

Token based authentication is much easier when your clients are non-browser based. So if you're targetting mobile applications, token based authentication is worth considering.

But also in a browser scenario it has some advantages. As the browser does not automatically send the `Authorization` header, security token are not vulnerable to [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) attacks.

If your web application lives on another domain than you API, cookies will not be sent because of the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Security tokens are not affected by this.